# How to dkms build / install a future kernel driver into current kernel?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, using kernel 4.15.0-72 on an Asrock J4105-ITX motherboard. I would like to use the NCT6796D chip on the motherboard to control the fan speeds. However, this particular chip is not supported by the nct6775.c driver in the current kernel.
It is however, supported in the [NCT6775](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hwmon/nct6775.c) driver with kernel 4.17.  How can I install the newer driver onto my current kernel. Ideally, I'd like to do this with DKMS so that I don't need to rebuild it everytime.

Thanks in advance for your help.  Cheers!!!

Comment: It might be easier just to install a newer kernel branch, either 4.18 or 5.0.

Comment: I did try installing 4.17 kernel but ran into other issues since I couldn't install drivers like zfs using apt get since the binaries were not built for that kernel.

Comment: That's why I suggested the 4.18 or 5.0 kernel branches; the ZFS packages should work for them.

Comment: @ajgringo619 could you please elaborate how exactly I would install a kernel from the 4.18 branch? Also, is there a particular minor version I'd have to use?   For the 4.17  kernel, I manually downloaded the debs from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: This link will get you to the 5.0 kernel: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-hwe-kernel/

Comment: @ajgringo619 this solved my issue.  Thanks for your help.